# how to stop multiple javascript else if conditions from firing in tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm new, sorry.

I made this tic tac toe game on a whim and it is getting out of control with else if statements. They are even worse when multiple difficulties are added because there are two more conditions like this one...

```
    else if (eckses.indexOf(3) != -1 && eckses.indexOf(2) != -1 && ohs.indexOf(1) == -1 && easy == false && medium == false){
            block = true;
            if ( cell == 1 ) {
            ohs.push(1);
            $(this).html("<p>O</p>").addClass("oh");
            spots.splice( $.inArray(1, spots), 1);  
            }
        }
```

So the problem is not only are they unwieldy, but I have 24 of them and randomly more than one will fire at once which means winning is nearly impossible and it looks glitchy. I made a fiddle where the majority of the code is (no difficulties). You can recreate the problem by clicking bottom left, top left, top right in that order it will cause the function to fire twice.

https://jsfiddle.net/x10e7o3j/

I've been trying for days to simplify and add some type of boolean to turn it off, but I cannot find a decent solution. It seemed too complicated for switch cases and for loops through arrays are a little out of my league.

So to clarify my question is based on the 24 else if statements that I have. Is there a better way, or at least a way to stop it from firing multiple times?

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: It works great, in Chrome PC

Comment: If i was doing it I would create a function to do the checks and if arrays are too hard then i think you are stuck with your if statements. You should spend a little time on arrays. They are very very useful and used all the time.

Comment: "for loops through arrays are a little out of my league.". Ok but maybe it's worth the time to learn on this occasion? They're a fundamental logical construct and building block of almost every programming language. You won't get very far with more than the most simple programs until you grasp them. And once  you get it, it'll come naturally and make lots of coding tasks suddenly seem simpler.